# Adding a completion handler to an asynchronous request method that only returns completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlsessiondatatask

So I've posted twice on this and I'm still pretty stuck ([post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418653/nsurlsessiondatatask-authentication-challenge/47424770#47424770), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434419/waiting-for-an-asyncronous-call-to-finish-within-a-completion-block/47437017#47437017)).

I want to trigger an authentication request when if I get a 401 challenge when calling another request. I have a completion block for my request so it receives the data and then can do something once it is received.

The problem is if I get my 401 I want to call authentication and then retry my request. I got an answer to my [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434419/waiting-for-an-asyncronous-call-to-finish-within-a-completion-block/47437017#47437017) saying that I should add a completion handler to my auth method so that it can call the original request. The problem is I have no idea how I can add only a completion block to my method. I've looked up blocks and tried a ray wenderlich tutorial but everything seems to be returning something or passing something aswell as a completion block.

```
+ (void)requestAuthToken {

    NSLog(@"requestNewToken - Called: Requesting a new authorization bearer token.");

    //Indicate Network Activity
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

    //Build request URL String
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,authRequestURL];

    //Encode password so that it can be safely sent in request
    NSString *encodedPassword = [kU1Password stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986];

    //Populate post request with user credentials
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&password=%@&grant_type=%@", kU1ClientId, encodedPassword, kU1GrantType];

    //Encode post string & convert to type NSData
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    //Calculate the length of the post string
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

    //Initialize url request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    //Set the url for which you will pass your request data
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];

    //Set HTTP method for request
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //Set HTTP header field with length of post data
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //Set the encoded value for HTTP Header field
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //Set the HTTP body of the urlrequest with our post data
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //Create full request
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"Status Code: %ld\n",(long)httpResponse.statusCode);

                                                    NSString *message = [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:httpResponse.statusCode];
                                                    NSLog(@"Message: %@", message);

                                                    //Check for an error, if there is no error we proceed.
                                                    if (!error) {

                                                        NSLog(@"requestAuthToken - Successful responce from server");

                                                        //Populate the auth object with the parse json data (handled entirely in the builder)
                                                        Token *auth = [TokenBuilder authFromJSON:data error:&error];
                                                        //Set the local tokens object equal to our responce object
                                                        //self.tokens = auth;

                                                        //Save the auth & refresh tokens in the keychain
                                                        [SAMKeychain setPassword:downloadedAuthToken forService:kServer account:kKeyAccessToken];
                                                        [SAMKeychain setPassword:downloadedRefreshToken forService:kServer account:kKeyRefreshToken];

                                                        //Get que and perform any UI changes
                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                            //_accessTokenLabel.text = _tokens.OOTAuthToken;
                                                            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        //Failed request
                                                        NSLog(@"requestAuthToken - error : %@", error.description);
                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

If I try to make the function return a bool, I can't actually return it within my completion block for the web request because it thinks i'm returning a value to the request, not the overarching method.

I also tried to use a delegate to pass a boolean through the completion block of the request but the boolean executes immediately (because of the async request) and is essentially useless.

How can I take `+ (void)requestAuthToken` and add a completion block to it so that rather than calling `self requestAuthToken` I can do `[self refreshAuth withCompletionHandler:weakself.requestDataForUser];` or even

```
[self requestAuthToken(^somethingblockyhere){
retry request
}];
```

Thanks

Comment: Do _not_ "post twice on this". If you didn't get the answer you wanted, don't accept that answer. If your question wasn't posed correctly, edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+animateWithDuration:animations:` of `UIView` is a simple example on how declare an void block.
It's declared like this:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations;
```

I personally never remember how to declare them, I alway check on an iOS SDK (I know a few methods) to remember the way of declaring them.

So applying to your question:

```
+ (void)requestAuthToken:(void (^)(void))block
{
    //do your thing

    //When it's okay:
    if (block)
    {
        block();
    }
}
```

On your other call (code taken from your other code):

```
-(void)requestDataForUser
{
    //Do your things

    //Need to refresh token:
    [[CorrectClassName requestAuthToken:^{
        [weakSelf requestDataForUser];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi Larme. I have implemented what you said and my method finally works! Many thanks for the help but I do have a question about this completion block you've put above. In regards to the `if(block) {block();}`, what does this code actually say? We aren't setting the value of block anywhere, its void right? I'm not quite sure I get how this one works and an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Imagine it as a C Method, or Swift Method looks-like with no parameter. It's just calling that "method" with no params. And `^{}];` the "implementation" of that method. If you don't want to do anything, just do `[CorrectClassName requestAuthToken:nil]`.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, once again thanks a lot for the help!